# Returning Dialogflow parameters from webhook after logic

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Can anyone please tell me which part of the Dialogflow response Json should I be interested in if I want to capture parameters apply some logic and then return them in the response body.
In python, I try capturing it with :

```
data.get('queryResult')
#and parameters as
params = data.get('queryResult').get('parameters')
```

which gives me :

```
{
  "responseId": "877c64d4-683d-4ee1-9a1a-15b6895a3fe4-2db64ae0",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "",
    "action": "action",
    "parameters": {
      ..............
      ]
    },
    "fulfillmentText": "----",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [

          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "lifespanCount": 2,
        "parameters": {
          ------

      },
      {
        "name": "projects/---/agent/sessions/------d8-58750c3ac41f/contexts/--_dialog_context",
        "lifespanCount": 2,
        "parameters": {
          ----------
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/b---/agent/sessions/----8-58750c3ac41f/contexts/vitals_dialog_params_x",
        "lifespanCount": 1,
        "parameters": {
        -----------
      },
      {
        "name": "-------------",
        "lifespanCount": 5,
        "parameters": {
          -------------
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/-------agent/sessions/a66dc4ee-0d0c-0f49-dad8-58750c3ac41f/contexts/__system_counters__",
        "lifespanCount": 1,
        --------------
}
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/------7/agent/intents/a7886182-9fa8-4c67-b361-3edc51a79465",
      "displayName": "intent_name"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 0.87550575,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 1039
    },
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 14,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE."
  },
  "alternativeQueryResults": [
    {
      "queryText": "blood pressure twice daily for three weeks",
      "outputContexts": [
        {
          "name": "projects/1111111/agent/sessions/a66dc4ee-0d0c-0f49-dad8-58750c3ac41f/contexts/base_vitals",
          "lifespanCount": 4,
          "parameters": {
           ---------
          }
        }
      ],
      "languageCode": "en"
    }
  ]
}
```

So far I've tried every capturing parameters field (and applying logic to it) in this JSON but nothin works. It doesn't make any difference. Am I looking in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would get the parameters you want from the `queryResult.parameters` section and would provide parameters to be used, either in the response or in subsequent webhooks, as parameters for a context you create in the `outputContext` section.

Comment: I'm trying to replace the value of some of the parameters based on some login. I want to send the response JSON to the front end with these replaced values. But I can't seem to achieve that. The response payload that I see on the front end always has the old values (that I tried to change through webhook) I'm not talking about the fulfillment text here.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and you can check out my post and my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363430/manipulating-a-specific-context-using-output-context-response).

Now what I did was I just changed the parameters from within the context and sent them in the response like this:

```
req.body.queryResult.outputContexts[0].parameters.param="value"


{
            "fulfillmentText": ${textToSpeech},
            "fulfillmentMessages": [{ "text": { "text": [${text}] } }],
            "payload": {
                "google": {
                    "expectUserResponse": true,
                    "richResponse": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "simpleResponse": {
                                    "textToSpeech": ${textToSpeech},
                                    "displayText": ${text}
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "suggestions": ${suggestions},
                        "linkOutSuggestion": {
                            "destinationName": "Feedback",
                            "url": ${feedbackURL}
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "outputContexts": ${req.body.queryResult.outputContexts}
        }
```

Comment: Sorry for asking a stupid question (I'm a beginner), but for confirmation when you say "sent them in the response like this" I'm assuming you sent (or returned this as a response to a function, if you will) this whole JSON right? Also, the ${} means you're referencing the values from your function or wherever you wrote e.g req.body.queryResult.outputContexts in your code?