# manipulating a specific context using output context response

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm currently trying to change a specific value of one of my context using webhook response and from what I [found](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook#context), the following should work:

```
       {
            "fulfillmentText": ${textToSpeech},
            "fulfillmentMessages": [{ "text": { "text": [${text}] } }],
            "payload": {
                "google": {
                    "expectUserResponse": true,
                    "richResponse": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "simpleResponse": {
                                    "textToSpeech": ${textToSpeech},
                                    "displayText": ${text}
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "suggestions": ${suggestions},
                        "linkOutSuggestion": {
                            "destinationName": "Feedback",
                            "url": ${feedbackURL}
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "outputContexts": [
                {
                  "name": "projects/${projectID}/agent/sessions/${conversationID}/contexts/${context}",
                  "lifespanCount": 15,
                  "parameters": { 
                    "param":"value"
                   }
                }]
        }
```

However, this does nothing to change any parameters specified within that context. Am I doing something incorrectly or is there a better method of changing parameters for an output context using webhook responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just managed to solve the issue.
Instead of trying to create my own output context i just manipulated the values in `req.body.queryResult.outputContexts`.

For example:
`req.body.queryResult.outputContexts[0].parameters.param="value"`

and then sent the response with the original outputContext

```
{
            "fulfillmentText": ${textToSpeech},
            "fulfillmentMessages": [{ "text": { "text": [${text}] } }],
            "payload": {
                "google": {
                    "expectUserResponse": true,
                    "richResponse": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "simpleResponse": {
                                    "textToSpeech": ${textToSpeech},
                                    "displayText": ${text}
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "suggestions": ${suggestions},
                        "linkOutSuggestion": {
                            "destinationName": "Feedback",
                            "url": ${feedbackURL}
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "outputContexts": ${req.body.queryResult.outputContexts}
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check how your Incoming Contexts are named.

Names can have [either of the following formats](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Context):

- `projects/<Project ID>/agent/sessions/<Session ID>/contexts/<Context ID>`
- `projects/<Project ID>/agent/environments/<Environment ID>/users/<User ID>/sessions/<Session ID>/contexts/<Context ID>`

If the contexts are coming in using the second format (which includes environment and user IDs), then you'll need to create contexts with similar names.

Specifically, you the part before `/contexts/<Context ID>` should match the full session string provided in the [WebhookRequest](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#webhookrequest) which, you guessed it, matches one of the following two patterns:

- `projects/<Project ID>/agent/sessions/<Session ID>`
- `projects/<Project ID>/agent/environments/<Environment ID>/users/<User ID>/sessions/<Session ID>`

Comment: Thanks for the resources.
I was using the first method and am still unsure what the actual issue was, but my fix seems to work so it's fine.